# Creating a simple text file based search engine

Tags: php

I need to create a simple text file based search engine asap (using PHP)! Basically it has to read files in a directory, remove stop and useless words, index each remaining useful word with how many times it appears in each document.

I guess the pseudo code for this is:

```
for each file in directory:
    read in contents,
    compare to stop words,
    add each remaining word to array,
    count how many times that word appears in document,
    add that number to the array,
    add the id/name of the file to the array,
```

also need to count the total amount of words (after useless removal i guess) in the whole file, which im guessing can be done afterwards as long as i can get the file id from that array and then count the words inside....?

Can anyone help, maybe provide a barebones structure? I think the main bit i need help with is getting the number of times each word appears in the document and adding it to the index array...

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$words=array();
foreach (glob('*') as $file) {
    $contents=file_get_contents($file);
    $words[$file]=array();
    preg_match_all('/\S+/',$contents,$matches,PREG_SET_ORDER);
    foreach ($matches as $match) {
        if (!isset($words[$file][$match[0]))
            $words[$file][$match[0]]=0;
        $words[$file][$match[0]]++;
    }
    foreach ($useless as $value)
        if (isset($words[$file][$value]))
            unset($words[$file][$value]);
    $count=count($words[$file]);
    var_dump($words[$file]);
    echo 'Number of words: '.$count;
}
```

Comment: thanks! i gave this a try and im just getting "ArrayArrayArrayArray" etc etc printed if i echo the words array... the count works fine but i need to store each word in the array and be able to retrieve it...

Comment: thanks, think im getting somewhere! (ignore previous comment, i was echo-ing rather than printing...) only thing is, how do i store the filename along side each word and amount in the array?

Comment: also im having trouble removing stop/useless words. i have an array of words im comparing to using array_diff, and when i compare that to the words array at the end, nothing seems to happen, no words are removed...

Comment: See edited code. $useless is the array of words you want to filter out.

Comment: thats brilliant! thank you so much! however i think what is happening is all occurrences of each word are being added and totaled in one, i need the key of the index to be the filename so for each file there is a record of each word and the number of times it appears... if you get me? so i think it would appear as [file.txt]=>airline,4 [file2.txt]=>airline,2 etc etc

Comment: edited again. i think it's close to what you need. don't forget to award the points if you think this answers your question :)

Comment: will do :) ok im now using GET to grab a search term from a submitted form, how do i search the array to find a match and then return the results? im tyring: <pre>if( preg_match_all('/' . $searchWord . '/', $words[$file], $matches2) ) {
     $count2 = count($matches2[0]);
 }

 echo $count2 . ' matches for the word ' . $searchWord . ' in the file ' .  $file . '<br />';</pre> but that does not return any results, it simply echos "matches for the word intels in the file ./files/africa.txt"

Comment: you should start a new Q&A for that

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [str_word_count](http://php.net/str_word_count). It counts words, but can also extract them to an array (each value in the array being a word). You can then post-process this array to remove stop words, count occurrences, etc.

Comment: +1, plus using something like `array_count_values` can be very small & fast.

Answer (score 1):

Well getting each file in the directory should be simple by using [glob](http://php.net/glob)
Then reading the files can be done with
[file_get_contents](http://php.net/file_get_contents)

```
/**
 * This is how you will add extra rows
 * 
 * $index[] = array(
 *  'filename' => 'airlines.txt',
 *  'word' => 'JFK',
 *  'count' => 3,
 *  'all_words_count' => 42
 * );
*/
$index = array();

$words = array('jfk', 'car');

foreach( $words as $word ) {

  // All files with a .txt extension
  // Alternate way would be "/path/to/dir/*"
  foreach (glob("test_files/*.txt") as $filename) {

    // Includes the file based on the include_path
    $content = file_get_contents($filename, true);

    $count = 0;

    $totalCount = str_word_count($content);

    if( preg_match_all('/' . $word . '/i', $content, $matches) ) {
      $count = count($matches[0]);
    }

    // And another item to the list
    $index[] = array(
        'filename' => $filename,
        'word' => $word,
        'count' => $count,
        'all_words_count' => $totalCount
      );

  }

}

// Debug and look at the index array,
// make sure it looks the way you want it.
echo '<pre>';
print_r($index);
echo '</pre>';
```

When I tested the above code, this is what I got.

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [filename] => test_files/airlines.txt
            [word] => jfk
            [count] => 2
            [all_words_count] => 38
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [filename] => test_files/rentals.txt
            [word] => jfk
            [count] => 0
            [all_words_count] => 47
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [filename] => test_files/airlines.txt
            [word] => car
            [count] => 0
            [all_words_count] => 38
        )

    [3] => Array
        (
            [filename] => test_files/rentals.txt
            [word] => car
            [count] => 3
            [all_words_count] => 47
        )

)
```

I think I have solved your question :D Add this to the after the above script and you should be able to sort the count, starting at zero with `$sorted` and from the highest with `$sorted_desc`

```
function sorter($a, $b) {
  if( $a['count'] == $b['count'] )
    return 0;

  return ($a['count'] < $b['count']) ? -1 : 1;
}

// Clone the original list
$sorted = $index;

// Run a custom sort function
uasort($sorted, 'sorter');

// Reverse the array to find the highest first
$sorted_desc = array_reverse($sorted);

// Debug and look at the index array,
// make sure it looks the way you want it.
echo '<h1>Ascending</h1><pre>';
print_r($sorted);
echo '</pre>';

echo '<h1>Descending</h1><pre>';
print_r($sorted_desc);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Thanks very much, this works for finding a search term, however i need it to count all the words in each document and record it!

Comment: brilliant thats great! i've been playing around with this and i'm having trouble getting each word to go into an array....

basically i want say in $index array to hold:

filename | word | number of times each word appears. 

i.e. airline.txt | airline | 5

Comment: ok thats great, but i need that for every word in each document, so instead of where you have $words = array('jfk','car'); i need it to take in every word in the document to create a huge index, get me? and then i must be able to search for a certain POST'ed word...

Comment: ok i think i've basically got it! all i need to do now is be able to order the results based on the count! :)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a basic structure:

1. Create an `$index` array
2. Use `scandir` (or `glob`, if you need to only get files of a certain type) to get the files in the directory.
3. For each file:

   1. Get contents with `file_get_contents`
   2. Use `str_word_count` to get array `$word_stream` of word stream
   3. Create an array `$word_array` to hold word counts
   4. For each word in `$word_stream`:

      1. If it is in a `$ignored_words` array, skip it
      2. If it is not already in `$word_array` as a key, add `$word_array[$word] = 1`
      3. If it is already in `$word_array`, increment `$word_array[$word]++`
   5. Get the sum of `$word_array` with `array_sum`, or the sum of unique words with `count`; you can add them to `$word_array` with keys `"_unique"` and `"_count"` (which will not be words), if you like
   6. Add the filename as a key to the `$index` array, with the value being `$word_array`