# Javascript: Adding a search ability in an internal site

Tags: javascript, html, search, search-engine

I have created a static web site on our company network.
It is not exposed to the internet.

They are pure HTML - no CSS or scripting so far.

I meant for it to be very simple cause I was very limited by time.

But, apparently, a search mechanism is required.

I found the google and other auto creators on the web. But they require ,as far as I understood, to set an internet web URL and do not support internal sites.

whereas my urls domain is in the form of:

http://192.168.4.XXX/something.htm

So, do you know a solution I can use? a free component or a **javascript** I can use?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What are you running to host the webpages on the local intranet like that?

If you are using some sort of server like Apache, or IIS, then it is possible to use a server side language to create your search functionality. Using pure Javascript on the client side is not practical to create a search functionality.

Here's an example of what a PHP script running on an Apache server can do https://stackoverflow.com/a/4090449/4422715 bear in mind, this is a very simple piece of code and there will definitely be issues, but for a small scale use, it might be worth doing something simple like this.

EDIT: OP stated IIS with ASP.

After a little looking around, I found this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7296/Reading-Files-in-ASP-and-How-to-Search-for-a-parti

The page where you enter the word you want to search should be like this, lets say "search.htm"

```
<FORM METHOD=POST id=form1 action="searchresult.asp"
                       name=form1 onsubmit="return Check();">
  Enter text to search for:
  <INPUT TYPE=TEXT NAME=TextToSearch>
  <P>
  <INPUT TYPE=SUBMIT VALUE="Begin Search!" id=SUBMIT1 name=SUBMIT1>
</FORM>
```

Then the "searchresult.asp" page should be:

```
'Search Text
Dim strtextToSearch
strtextToSearch = Request("TextToSearch")

'Now, we want to search all of the files
Dim fso

'Constant to read
Const ForReading = 1
Set fso = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

'Specify the folder path to search.
Dim FolderToSearch
FolderToSearch = "D:\temp"

'Proceed if folder exists
if fso.FolderExists(FolderToSearch) then

    Dim objFolder
    Set objFolder = fso.GetFolder(FolderToSearch)

    Dim objFile, objTextStream, strFileContents, bolFileFound
    bolFileFound = False

    Dim FilesCounter
    FilesCounter = 0 'Total files found

    For Each objFile in objFolder.Files
        Set objTextStream = fso.OpenTextFile(objFile.Path,ForReading)
        'Read the content
        strFileContents = objTextStream.ReadAll
        If InStr(1,strFileContents,strtextToSearch,1) then
           Response.Write objFile.Name & "<br>"
           FilesCounter = FilesCounter + 1
        End If
        objTextStream.Close
    Next

    if FilesCounter = 0 then
        Response.Write "Sorry, No matches found."
    else
        Response.Write "Total files found : " & FilesCounter
    end if

    'Destroy the objects
    Set objTextStream = Nothing
    Set objFolder = Nothing

else
    Response.Write "Sorry, invalid folder name"
end if
Set fso = Nothing
```

Above is a copy paste directly from linked website. Have a look at the linked website and read through the code before you run it!!! Make sure set "FolderToSearch" to your root document folder.

Looks like this code will look at only the files directly in the folder you set it to search in. If you want it to read subfolders and so on, then you will need to figure out how to do that sorry, I am not an ASP expert, you could post this code on the ASP part of the website and for someone's help with directory recursion with this script.

Comment: the site is on IIS. I am very new to web programming, ant thus I have no experience in Html/CSS/Javascript/php/etc. Can you point me to a code which will fit my needs on IIS instead apache? Thanks

Comment: Sure, I'll give it a go and update the answer above :)

Comment: Added some code. Hope that helps :)

Comment: I think that I will be able to deal with the sub folder search issue. But - regarding the path: I my files are in \\172.20.4.107\c$\KB\, what should I set as FolderToSearch ? c:\KB ?

Comment: Hmmm. No, you need to put the folder where the raw files exist on the computer running the IIS server. There must be a place where the files physically exist. You could try look inside the IIS installation folder for a folder called "htdocs" usually servers put the docs in a folder like that. Or it could be somewhere else, I really am not familiar enough with IIS to tell you where to look exactly. But you should be able to find it in the settings for the program at the very least! Good luck :). Feel free to ask more

Comment: it should be c:\KB\ and it works! I just need to find out how to print the links, because currently it only gives me the names of the files, and I'd like to display the links to the files.

Comment: Ohhh that's fine, change the code and convert it to <a href=""></a> sort of links :) should be possible with a bit of fiddling around! Someone over at ASP with more knowledge will definitely be able to sort that one out for you